# Why we shouldn't believe that $\pi(x)$ has connection to the constant $\pi$?

Tags: prime-numbers, notation, pi

It is well known that $\pi(x)$ is the prime counting function , This notation was introduced by number theorist Edmund Landau in 1909 if we define this function as:

$\pi:\mathbb{Z}\to  \mathbb{Z} $ then we have the application is $\pi$ which it is identical to the constant $\pi=3.14\dotso$.  Why do number theorists define this function using the constant  $\pi$?  Is there any connection?  and how they weren't afraid about confusing between prime counting function and $\pi$ constant?

Comment: $\pi$ is the first letter of "prime".

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. FYI, in the future, please consider if this type of question might be better suited for the [History of Science and Mathematics](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/) SE site instead.

Comment: $\pi$ as the Greek letter Pi, which encodes the sound /p/, which is the initial sound of the translation of *prime* in all languages except the ones where it isn't. They were not afraid of confusion because of the presence of an argument to the function.

Comment: @AnginaSeng Well, strictly speaking, the first letter of "prime" is p, not $\pi$.

Comment: There is no relation (well, no direct relation) between $\pi(x)$ and the constant $\pi$, it's just an unfortunate choice of notation, introduced by Edmund Landau (see [this](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeCountingFunction.html)).

Comment: @Gae.S. Which is a poor justification, as the product of $\pi$ and $x+1$ is noted $\pi(x+1)$...

Comment: We could spend the rest of eternity debating overloading of names in mathematics. I remember many years ago getting a giggle from a class-mate and a kindly-ish glare from a lecturer when I conjectured out loud that in $H(H)$ (intended to be the homology groups of a group $H$) the second $H$ must be a capital $\eta$. Mathematical notation evolves over time and does not always follow orderly rules: we just have to live with that - that's part of mathematical maturity.

Comment: "π:Z→Z then we have the application is π which it is identical to the constant π=3.14..." No, you have a function that has the same *name*. Lot's of things have the same name but are different things.  The movie "Jojo Rabbit" and those long ear mammals that eat carrots.  The northwestern most continental United State and the first President of the United Sates. The mathematician who invented this notation and the actor from the television series "Mission Impossible" etc... "how they weren't afraid about confusing between prime counting function and $\pi$ constant ? " Apparently not.

Comment: To complicate matters further, $\pi$ is also frequently used as a variable name for a **p**ermutation.  The end result is that there are only a relatively small number of symbols we have available to use and a larger number of objects that we will want to be able to notate.  It is clear from context which is meant, just as it is clear from context  which homonym is meant in a sentence like "My dog will **bark** at a squirrel climbing up the **bark** of a tree"

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut I don't see the choice of notation as being unfortunate at all.  $\pi$ means many things in different contexts:  the circle constant, the prime counting function, a projection map, a permutation, a homotopy group (with a subscript), and so on.  There are only finitely many symbols, and a virtually infinite number of concepts which we might want to represent with those symbols.  Some overlap is bound to occur.

Comment: @John_Omelian I disagree. This question is about notation and perfectly on topic on this site.

Comment: @J.-E.Pin , am confused how people saw this is normally thing which we shouldn't confusing prime counting function with pi constant , In the same time no one give me the reason why theorist took this notation with pi constant surly there is some clear reason

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut No, you cannot write an infinite number of words with a finite number of symbols, nor can you conceptualize an infinite number of symbols (or concepts).  I am referring to the pragmatics of actually practicing mathematics, not the mathematical study of symbolic dynamics or first order logic.  All mathematicians on Earth will, over history of our species (past and future) use only a finite number of symbols, and will want to represent a much, much, *much* larger number of concepts.  Some overlap is bound to occur.  I don't see this as unfortunate, as context saves the day.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Yes, and...? Linguists have long observed that the length of a word (in pretty much any language) is (roughly) inversely proportional to the frequency of that word.  That is, more commonly used words are shorter. In number theory, the prime counting function is used frequently. It is expected and reasonable that this function should have a short, pithy name. Moreover, in this context, the circle constant doesn't come up that often (until you start to complexify things, I suppose), thus the chance for ambiguity is slight. I still fail to see how the notation is "unfortunate".

Answer (score 3):

You are right, and this concern about frozen notation was addressed by Paul R. Halmos in his famous article [How to write mathematics](https://sites.math.washington.edu/~lind/Resources/Halmos.pdf):

> As history progresses, more and more symbols get frozen. The standard
>   examples are $e$, $i$ and $\pi$, and, of course, $0,1,2,3, \ldots$
>   (Who would dare write “Let $6$ be a group.”?) A few other letters are
>   almost frozen: many readers would fell offended if $n$ were used for a
>   complex number, $\epsilon$ for a positive integer, and $z$ for a
>   topological space. (A mathematician’s nightmare is a sequence
>   $n\varepsilon$ that tends to $0$ as $\varepsilon$ becomes infinite.)

This is why Halmos recommends against freezing new symbols. Now, regarding your question about $\pi(x)$, it was observed in the comments that Landau's notation applies to a function, but it was also observed that $\pi(x+1)$ is still be ambiguous. Thus the risk exists but hopefully the context should be sufficient to avoid any confusion.

Computer scientists also face this problem but solve it in two different ways. First, by using *types*: the constant $\pi$ (of type real number) is a different object than the function $\pi:{\Bbb Z} \to {\Bbb Z}$. Secondly, by using *local variables*: the scope of a local variable is limited to the function that contains its definition and hence the same letter can be reused for another local variable. This is exactly what we do when we reuse $n$ in $\sum_n x_n$ and $\sum_n y_n$. Extrapolating on this notion, Landau's notation can be seen as *local* to number theory.

Comment: Upvoted for the reference to Halmos, alone.  I've always thought that his "How to write mathematics" should be standard reading.  The rest of the answer is spot on, too. (+1)

Answer (score 2):

There was no fear of confusion for the same reason that $i=\sqrt {-1}$ is rarely confused with an index like 
$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty{x^i}$$
It's because they appear in different contexts. It's not true that $\pi$ never shows up in number theory, but if the constant $\pi$ is intended it would usually not have parentheses after as it would as the prime counting function. If there were potential for confusion, most authors would contort their notation to avoid this.